# Цикл for без параметров

Tags: циклы, java

```
for (; ; k = p[k - 1]) {

}
```

Как это понимать? Как действует этот цикл?

Comment: А язык-то какой? Такой цикл может и ошибку выдать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это означает, что в цикле отсутствуют операторы инициализации и проверки условия.
Будет выполняться `k = p[k - 1]`, пока цикл не прервется изнутри, например, по `break`.

Comment: @DarkGenius Спасибо, а заменить чем-нибудь возможно эту конструкцию, уж больно глаз не радует.

Comment: @thejadefalcon:

    while (true)
        k = p[k - 1];

возможно, более читаемо.

Comment: Как сказал @VladD, лучше, можно так еще:

    for ( ; ; ) {
       k = p[k - 1]
    }

Answer (score 2):

Это значит, что у цикла нет условий для продолжения, а следовательно, он будет бесконечным. Ну точнее не совсем уж бесконечным - раз тело у цикла пустое, то скорее всего в нем просто вывалится исключение, но многое тут зависит от начального значения k и от содержимого p.

Также для вящей точности было бы неплохо указать, о каком языке идет речь - подобная конструкция возможна во многих языках

Однако в любом случае без своевременного break вывалится исключение - рано или поздно k выйдет за пределы допустимых индексов массива p. [Небольшой пример](http://ideone.com/r6u3gZ)

Comment: @DreamChild Java

Comment: @DreamChild: ну, для случая `k = 1`, `p = { 0 }` не вывалится. А так-то вообще обычный обход [связного списка](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array):

    class LinkedList<T>
    {
        int[] next;
        T[] data;
    }

Comment: @VladD ошибаетесь. Вывалится

Comment: @DreamChild: http://ideone.com/fTaeCk

А, ну да, `p = { 1 }`.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно цикл имеет следующую структуру:

```
for([инициализация];[условие_выхода];[шаг])
{
    [тело_цикла]
}
```

В квадратных скобках указаны необязательные параметры.

Инициализация - выполняется один раз перед началом цикла. Условие - проверяется каждый раз перед началом выполнения тела цикла(код). Шаг - выполняется каждый раз после выполнения тела цикла (код).

Цикл может выглядеть и так:

```
for(;;);
```

Но полезность его стремится к нулю. Обычно, когда не указывается условие выхода, цикл становится бесконечным. Но его можно прервать, поместив в тело цикла ключевое слово `break;`. Так делают, когда не знают, как точно он должен прерваться, и нужна множественная проверка:

```
for(;;)
{
    if(...) break;
    if(...) break;

    [еще какой-то код]

}
```

Можно еще привести похожий while, но for читается лучше:

```
[инициализация]
while([условие_выхода])
{
    [тело_цикла]
    [шаг] 
}
```